# Working with Java

Tags: java

How do I read an array from a text file in java?

Comment: Doesn't make sense, put your text file example in the question.

Comment: I agree with Scott.  Also, make the title a cogent inquisition.

Answer (score 1):

You can read strings from a text file, line-by-line if you want.

You'd then have to parse the lines (or file contents) from Strings into an array. How that works depends on how your file is formatted.

If you are using standard formats like JSON or CSV, you can use libraries for this.